# Does requestAnimationFrame can be stuck by long javascript

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I know the **requestAnimationFrame** be invoked before the re-rendering of the browser, and the frequency is about 60fps, but if there is a very long javascript in the callback of **requestAnimationFrame** does it can block the re-rendering of the Browser? and therefore stuck the next **requestAnimationFrame**?

And move over, Why the browser re-rendering in 60fps, if there no content or style changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

As with any event-based function call (`requestAnimationFrame`, `setTimeout`, `addEventListener`, etc.) if the JS engine is *busy* running another function (even the same function from an earlier iteration) then the new function can't run until the previous one is finished.

Comment: Right, I do a test and proved it. What about the second question "And move over, Why the browser re-rendering in 60fps, if there no content or style changed?"

Comment: @sinbar — No idea. Avoid asking multiple questions at once. "Not enough focus" is a standard close reason.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a game developer and quite familiar with this. Any frame that takes too long to render will not only drop the frame-rate but will also lock up the DOM.

I strongly suggest you look into webworkers and offscreen canvas'. This allows you to push heavy loads into background processes that won't interfere with animation frames or the DOM.

An couple of excellent demos can be found here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/08/offscreen-canvas

Answer (score -1):

While what you said is true regarding 60fps, only sometimes as per the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

> requestAnimationFrame() calls are paused in most browsers when running in background tabs or hidden iframes in order to improve performance and battery life.